# Cannot include js file in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In my HTML file, I included a script like:

`<script src="js/index.js"></script>`

In my script, I try to add a `configuration.js` file just by writing `const Configuration = require("./configuration");`. `configuration.js` is in the same folder with `index.js`. But on console it says:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './configuration'
```

configuration.js and index.js files are both in `/app/js/` folder.

What is a solution to that? I can include Node.js modules like Lodash for example.

Comment: change require("./js/configuration"); maybe done.

Comment: @AhbapAldirmaz it worked, actually. I don't understand why though. If you can add an answer, I'll mark it correct. **edit**: Oh, I guess the path is relative to the html file. That solves it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to understand what is happening when you require a module, you could read [the docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_all_together).

On the first look, your code snippets should work. To require **a module** inside node.js, you always use the path from the file.

But, in your case, you are just importing plain JS. In this case, the script runs out of your HTML call.

That logic could cause a lot of other problems, so I would recommend you to create your own modules. node.js makes that very easy.

```
var configuration = {a: 1,b: 2};
module.exports = configuration;
```

More reading aout that:

- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/modules.html
- http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Inside your HTML file, you could put your modules together via require statements.